# How to define a repeated array only once in a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

Shown above is a formula, where, in the highlighted parts, the **same** **data values** are entered manually as an array. My goal is to simplify the formula so that the array of values is entered only once in a formula.

The LET function looked like a possible solution but it is not available in older versions of Excel.

My question is how can I define only one array, so it can be used for multiple calculations in the same formula? The solution has to be supported by all Excel versions, including Excel Online and for Mac.

Comment: You may be able to use a Named Formula  `(Formula=>Define Name)`.  Although you cannot create it in Excel Online, you can create it in Windows or Mac and it will then be recognized in Online.

Comment: BTW SORT is also not available in older versions.

Comment: for older versions sort can be replaced with: `SMALL({0.5;7;9;5},ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNT({0.5;7;9;5}))))` But this makes it an array formula and in older versions it will need to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

Comment: SORT is available in the used versions for this solution, so it is not an issue here. The issue is to define an array only once inside the formula or in one separate single cell.

Comment: LET and SORT are all used by the same versions.  If one has SORT then one should have LET.

Comment: Sorry upon further research, you are correct it is not available on ipads,iphone,android phone and android tablet.  But all other mac, online and pc that have SORT should have LET.

Comment: In the Microsoft 365 Enterprise version, the SORT function is available but not the LET function.

Comment: That is what I have and I have LET.  Maybe it needs to be updated?

Comment: I tried to update it but it is not there. Is there a similar alternative to the LET function to simplify this formula?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ron Rosenfeld in his comment, you can use a named formula to refer to the array by clicking on Formulas > Define Name, and typing in the array. Depending on the readability of your formula shown in the formula bar, you could choose to also name other parts of the formula, like this for example:

```
varArray = {0.5;7;9;5}
fxCount = COUNT(varArray)*0.25+0.5
fxSort = SORT(varArray,1)
```

Note that if you decide to later change the name *varArray* it will automatically be updated in the other named formulas. You can then insert these names into the formula:

```
=(INDEX(fxSort, CEILING(fxCount-0.5,1))+INDEX(fxSort, FLOOR(fxCount+0.5,1)))/2
```

Here is what it should look like in Excel with the Name Manager window open:
[image: name_manager]

If you open the file in Excel Online, you can use the named formulas but you cannot edit them nor add new ones.